# How to migrate Input/OutputChannel from Scala Actors to Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

According to this guide:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html

```
scala.actors._ -> akka.actor._
```

However there does not seeem to be `InputChannel`/`OutputChannel`/`Channel`.

So to migrate from Scala Actors to Akka Actors, where can I find those Channel APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might want is contained in the latest version of Akka and is called Typed Channels. It's marked as experimental because its a new feature and will probably be in flux for a bit but I believe it's similar to what you are looking for.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/typed-channels.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SynapseGrid](https://github.com/Primetalk/SynapseGrid/) library that can be a replacement for typed channels between actors.

One can create a so called "Contact" that can be shared between actors.

In one actor (Subsystem) one passes data to the contact:

```
val someInput = contact[String]("someInput")
val SharedContact = contact[String]("SharedContact")
outputs(SharedContact)
someInput.map("Hello, "+_)>>SharedContact
```

In another actor it appears on the same contact ready for consumption:

```
inputs(SharedContact)
SharedContact.map(_+"!").foreach(s => println("Got from other actor: "+s))
```

Everything is strictly typed.

However, SynapseGrid is more suitable for large systems.